# Solving the functional equation $2f(x)=f(x+a_n)+f(x-a_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits-and-convergence, functional-equations

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of strictly positive real numbers such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$. Find all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that admit primitives (i.e. there exists a function $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{dF(x)}{dx}=f(x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$) and satisfy the following equality $$2f(x)=f(x+a_n)+f(x-a_n), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
I have already posted this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4634456/trying-to-solve-a-functional-equation) but I got no answer.

Comment: The only such function $f$ is $f(x)=ax+b$. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440179/a-functional-equation/440189#440189 or https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114875/on-equation-fz1-fz-fz/114878#114878 for the explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On equation $f(z+1)-f(z)=f'(z)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114875/on-equation-fz1-fz-fz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}$This problem can be solved by using the Fourier transform -- cf. [this previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/440186/36721).

Let us present here an elementary solution:

Letting $G_n(x):=F(x+a_n)+F(x-a_n)-2F(x)$, we get $G'_n(x)=f(x+a_n)+f(x-a_n)-2f(x)=0$ for all $x$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    c_n:=G_n(x) \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
does not depend on $x$.

Take any real $A$ and $B$ such that $A<B$. Let $k_n:=\lfloor\frac{B-A}{a_n}\rfloor$, so that
\begin{equation*}
    k_n\sim \frac{B-A}{a_n},
\end{equation*}
$A+k_n a_n\to B$, and, by \eqref{1}, $\De_x(a_n):=F(x+a_n)-F(x)=\De_{x-a_n}(a_n)+c_n$ for all $x$, so that
\begin{equation*}
    F(A+k_n a_n)-F(A)=k_n \De_A(a_n)+\frac{k_n(k_n-1)}2\,c_n \\ 
    =(1+o(1))(B-A)\frac{\De_A(a_n)}{a_n}+\frac{1+o(1)}2\,(B-A)^2\frac{c_n}{a_n^2}, 
\end{equation*}
whence
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\De_A(a_n)}{a_n}
=(1+o(1))\frac{F(A+k_n a_n)-F(A)}{B-A}-\frac{1+o(1)}2\,(B-A)\frac{c_n}{a_n^2}. \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
Similarly, for any real $C>B$,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\De_A(a_n)}{a_n}
=(1+o(1))\frac{F(A+m_n a_n)-F(A)}{C-A}-\frac{1+o(1)}2\,(C-A)\frac{c_n}{a_n^2}, \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}
where $m_n:=\lfloor\frac{C-A}{a_n}\rfloor$.

The function $F$ is differentiable and hence continuous. So, $F(A+k_n a_n)\to F(B)$ and $F(A+m_n a_n)\to F(C)$. Subtracting now \eqref{2} from \eqref{3}, we get
\begin{equation}
    \frac12\,\frac{c_n}{a_n^2}\to\frac{\De_A(C-A)-\De_A(B-A)}{C-B}.
\end{equation}
It follows now by \eqref{2} that $\frac{\De_A(a_n)}{a_n}$ converges to a finite limit as well, and thus
\begin{equation}
    F(B)-F(A)=K_1(B-A)+\frac{K_2}2\,(B-A)^2
\end{equation}
for some real $K_1,K_2$ and all real $A$ and $B$ such that $A<B$.

We conclude that $F$ is a quadratic polynomial and hence $f=F'$ is an affine function. (Vice versa, any affine function $f$ satisfies your system of functional equations.)

---

The above proof can be simplified a bit by noting that the limit of $\frac{\De_A(a_n)}{a_n}$ exists (and equals $F'(0)$). However, the advantage of the above proof is that it shows that the conclusion that the only solutions to the system \eqref{1} of functional equations are quadratic polynomials can be reached assuming a priori only the continuity of $F$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\de\delta$Let us also present the Fourier transform argument, assuming that $|F|$ is bounded by a polynomial, so that $F$ may be considered a (tempered) distribution (in the generalized-function sense). Let then $\hat F$ denote the Fourier transform of $F$.

Equation (1) in the [other answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/440497/36721) yields
$$c_n\de(t)=\hat G_n(t)=e^{ita_n}\hat F(t)+e^{-ita_n}\hat F(t)-2\hat F(t)
=2\hat F(t)(\cos ta_n-1),$$
where $\de$ is the delta function.

If the equality $\cos ta_n-1=0$ takes place for some real $t$ and all $n$, then $t=0$ (since the $a_n$'s are nonzero and go to $0$). So,
the support of $\hat F$ is $\{0\}$. So (see e.g. "For every compact subset $K\subseteq U$ there exist constants
$C_{K}>0$ and $N_{K}\in \mathbb {N}$ such that for all $f\in C_{c}^{\infty }(U)$ with support contained in $K$ [...]" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Definitions_of_test_functions_and_distributions)), we have $\hat F=\sum_{j=0}^n a_j\de^{(j)}$ for some $n\in\{0,1,\dots\}$ and some complex $a_j$'s, where $\de^{(j)}$ is the $j$th derivative of the delta function $\de$. So, $F$ is a polynomial. Since the second difference $G_n$ of $F$ is (the) constant ($c_n$), it follows that the polynomial $F$ is quadratic. Thus, $f=F'$ is an affine function. (Vice versa, any affine function $f$ satisfies your system of functional equations.)

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : Thank you for your comment. This is now fixed.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : You seem to be referring to Theorem 16.4.1 in Hormander's *The analysis of linear partial differential operators*. However, (i) that theorem seems to describe only **smooth** solutions and (ii) it describes them as **limits** in $C^\infty$ of linear combinations of exponential solutions. So, I don't see ready-to-use more general conditions there. On the other hand, the simple and elementary solution at https://mathoverflow.net/a/440497/36721 is indeed more general, as it is applicable to any continuous $F$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : I cannot understand your latter comment. It does not seem to contain a sentence.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : Again, I do not understand your latter comment. In my first answer, the Fourier transform is not used at all. In my second answer, the polynomial growth condition is imposed, under which the Fourier transform does exist. However, the issue now is with **your** "more general" claim, discussed in my long comment, to which I have not seen an adequate response.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : How do you propose to do that (of course without requiring the $C^\infty$ condition)? My first answer here does exactly do that, in a simple and elementary way, only assuming the continuity of $F$. On the other hand, you seemed to claim to have more general conditions in your answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438494/solutions-of-complex-linear-difference-equations/438533#438533 -- but, after all this discussion, I still do not see more general conditions there. ??

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : (i) But my first answer here does exactly do that, in a simple and elementary way, only assuming the continuity (not even of $f$) but of $F$. Do you recognize that? (ii) Do you give up on your claim that you had more general conditions in your answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438494/solutions-of-complex-linear-difference-equations/438533#438533 ?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : Let me try to summarize our discussion. (i) You agree that my first answer on this page is general. (ii) You said that your answer at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438494/solutions-of-complex-linear-difference-equations/438533#438533 is more general than my second answer on this page. However, this does not appear quite true -- because your answer is based on a certain theorem, which, in contrast with my answer, describes only **smooth** solutions and describes them only as certain **limits**. Do you agree with this summary? If not, then specifically why not?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : No, exponentials are not dense in the set of smooth solutions. It is linear combinations of exponentials that are dense in the set of smooth solutions. And then, limits of such linear combinations do not have to be exponentials or even linear combinations of exponentials. How would you deal with that? I think, if you insist on your "more general" claim, you can just post a detailed answer with such a more general result -- **based on the theorem you previously linked**.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : Your solutions in the previous answers are at best incomplete, for the reasons that I have stated several times, even in my latter comment above. So, I suggest you remove your "more general" comments here.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : BTW, was it you who downvoted both of my answers on this page, even the one with "this problem [...] solved in full generality", in your words?

Comment: No, I did not downvote.